# Change a field type using Migrate

Tags: migrations

Can I migrate a Drupal 7 field from one field type to another using Migrate and `$this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;`?

I'm trying to move field_phone which is an ordinary Field API text field into a mobile_number field which is also a Field API field but provided by the [Mobile number](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_number) module.

uid is the only listed source field, and that makes sense because it's the only field selected in the query, but I don't see any examples that use JOINs to select data from fields attached to an entity.

How do I add field_phone to the source?

```
public function __construct($arguments) {
  $this->sourceFields['field_phone'] = t('Phone');
  parent::__construct($arguments);

  $this->systemOfRecord = Migration::DESTINATION;

  $query = db_select('users', 'u')
    ->fields('u', array('uid'))
    ->condition('uid', 0, '>');
  $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

  $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationUser(array());

  $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
    array('uid' => array(
      'type' => 'int',
      'unsigned' => TRUE,
      'default' => 0,
      'description' => "User's {users}.uid.",
    )), 
    MigrateDestinationUser::getKeySchema()
  );  
  $this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'uid');
  $this->addFieldMapping('field_phone_number', 'field_phone');
}
```

Additionally, If I can keep the same field machine name I rather do that then moving from field_phone to field_phone_number, but it's not important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard for me to believe, but the results are telling.  The source fields were never loaded, so they weren't available to the destination handler.  I added the following `prepare()` function to my Migration class so that the values would be available.  I don't see any examples that look like this, so I'm almost certain there's a better way.

```
function prepareRow($current_row) {
  if (parent::prepareRow($current_row) === FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  $phone = db_select("field_data_field_phone", "p")
    ->fields("p", array("field_phone_value"))
    ->condition("p.entity_type", "user")
    ->condition("p.entity_id", $current_row->uid)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchField();
  $current_row->field_phone = $phone;
}
```